# jQuery selector with variable, not updating when variable changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

'I am trying to do something like the below that will run a function when clicking the "hit" class only when the parent "box" id is correct.

```
var selected = 1;    

$('#box-' + selected + ' .hit').click(function(){

    selected = randomFromTo(1,5);

});
```

The `selected` variable changes depending on other actions on the page but I can't get the function to work after any change - it stays fixed to the initially selected "box" id.  I can imagine why this might be, as jQuery has taken a snapshot of that string and nothing is telling it update it but I can't figure out how to get around this.

**Edit:** added the selected variable's instantiation and where it gets set.  I've left out the UI changes that would make this more understandable to a user.

Comment: can u provide more code? the code that sets the variable, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set the click handler on the `.hit` class, then check the parent nodes for the right ID within the handler itself. If you do this, make sure you defer the event correctly, otherwise you'll end up with one handler for every single `.hit` element.

Comment: As it turned out I only wanted this to work on the `hit` area anyway, hence the class name - just wasn't paying attention.  Solved two problems in one ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the issue is that the `selected` variable is evaluated at the time your function is created. The function is bound to the `click` event of a set of DOM elements at that time.

After the binding, it is not possible to modify the selector, and changing any variable used during selection will have no effect.

The best way around this I can think of, is to attach the click event to all possible matches, and then further filter them inside the `click` handler...

```
$('.hit').click(function(){
    // check if the parent has the correct id
    if($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'box-' + selected){
        //function
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 I wrote this from Kolink's answer but thanks :) also the hash needs removing from before `box` as it's looking for an id already.

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this:

```
var selected = null;
function setSelected(aSelected) {

    if (selected !== null) {
        // Remove existing selected click handler
        $('#box-' + selected + ' .hit').off('click.selected')
    }

    selected = aSelected;

    // Click handler for new selected el
    $('#box-' + selected + ' .hit').on('click.selected', function() { });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the whole context to understand,
but at the first look it seems the posted code is being run once on your page.

So if You do

```
var selected = something;

$('#box-' + selected + ' .hit').click(function(){

    //function

});
```

and later on

```
selected = "newvalue";
```

this will not change program behaviour, the click event is already set for specific objects.

The other suggestion to set click handler on .hit makes a lot of sense, and then inside the handler You could check if

```
($(this).parent().attr('id')) == ("box-"+selected)
```

and only then execute Your code.

Comment: Not quite equivalent. This would be true if the selector were `"#box-"+selected+">.hit"`, but it's not - the box could be any ancestor.